How to prove the relationship between a decrypted value and its ciphertext using Zero-Knowledge Proofs?
I am currently working on a cryptographic project and I am looking for an efficient way to link a ciphertext to its decrypted value without revealing the value itself. Specifically, I am using the Paillier Encryption scheme for computations.
Problem Description
In my system, I encrypt data (e.g., insurance-related information such as premiums) using Paillier encryption. For instance:

Plaintext: ( M ) (e.g., an insurance premium value).
Ciphertext: ( C = g^M r^n \mod n^2 ).

I need to prove to a verifier that a decrypted value ( M ) (calculated client-side) corresponds to the ciphertext ( C ), without revealing ( M ). Additionally, I want to ensure that the proof is compact and efficient, as the system operates in a distributed setting (e.g., blockchain-based).
Requirements

Zero-Knowledge Proof:

The verifier should be convinced that ( M ) corresponds to ( C ), without learning the plaintext ( M ).


Range Constraints:

( M ) must also belong to a valid range (e.g., ( M \in [0, 10,000] )).


Compactness:

The proof must be efficient in terms of size and computation.



Approaches I Have Considered

Schnorr-based ZKP:

I tried adapting the Schnorr protocol for this, but encountered issues integrating it with the properties of Paillier encryption, as Schnorr is designed for multiplicative groups and doesn't directly work with Paillier’s additive homomorphism.


Bulletproofs:

I explored Bulletproofs for their efficient range proofs and compact size. However, I am unsure how to extend Bulletproofs to link a Pedersen Commitment or similar structure to a Paillier ciphertext.


Other ZKPs:

I looked into more generic ZKP protocols (e.g., zk-SNARKs), but they often require complex setups or trusted configurations, which I would like to avoid.



Tools and Frameworks

I am currently using Python with the phe library for Paillier encryption.
I am open to integrating Bulletproofs or other efficient ZKP libraries.

Question
How can I efficiently prove the relationship between a Paillier ciphertext ( C ) and its decrypted value ( M ) using a Zero-Knowledge Proof? Are there specific protocols or adaptations (e.g., Bulletproofs, zk-SNARKs) that are well-suited for this use case?

Any guidance, examples, or references to existing protocols would be greatly appreciated!

So basically, what you want is a zero-knowledge proof that a given commitment contains the same value as a Paillier ciphertext, and that this value belongs to a certain range, is that right?
Is there any specific motivation for wanting to use a commitment, or would it suffice to prove that the Paillier encryption contains a message $M$ in a given range? Also, who owns what? The client has the Paillier secret key? The prover too?
